# Grep with quotation mark

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to scan an error log for lines with 503 errors, so I'm grepping for `" 503` (quote space 503).

This seems simple, but it won't work:

```
grep '" 503 ' access.log
```

I get the following error:

> bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
>   bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: This should work. You sure you did not alias grep or something like that? "which grep"? "type grep"?

Comment: The error message shows "bash -c", so are you doing something like attempting to embed single quotes inside single quotes?

Comment: Hmm, works for me in bash exactly as you have it

Comment: Yes, I use grep often with no issues.

Comment: @Michael the "problem" with modern shells is, that they often escape stuff like this automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to some erroneous directives in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 18):

Seems like you are running it via some system() in some language, aren't you? Try:

```
grep '\" 503 ' access.log
```

or:

```
grep "\" 503 " access.log
```

Directly in shell just `grep '" 503 ' access.log` will work. To reproduce your problem I must do:

```
bash -c 'grep '\" 503 ' access.log'
```

This is indeed syntax error. To make that work, I need:

```
bash -c 'grep "\" 503 " access.log'
```

You are somehow calling `bash -c ...`. Maybe indirectly. You need to figure you how it's called to figure out what quotes are in collision.

Comment: No, directly in the shell. I've tried both examples you suggest with no luck.

Comment: this is strange. Can you post output of "type grep" and "echo $0" ?

Answer (score 1):

To debug strange effects like this, use "set -x" to show the shell expansions, and what the computer thinks about your command.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have it working now (not sure because I got no results, but didn't get an error).

The reason is because I'm passing it through an ssh command like the following and I believe SSH is doing some escape trickery:

```
ssh 123.123.123.123 grep '" 503 ' access.log
```

Modifiying it to this seems to be the fix:

```
ssh 123.123.123.123 "grep '\" 503 ' access.log"
```

Thanks for everyone's time.

Comment: It's not ssh that's doing the trickery, it's the shell.  Your local shell interprets the single quotation marks, and strips them from the `'" 503 '` argument, then passes those arguments to ssh.  ssh then passes the arguments it got, unchanged, to the shell on the remote system.  That shell sees an unmatched double-quote character.  (There's probably a bit more to it than that, but that's the general idea.)

Comment: @Keith is exactly right.  Since your command gets interpreted twice (once by your local shell and a second time by the remote shell) anything that normally must be quoted once must instead be quoted twice.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that though. Just was easier to call it trickery. :)